# Find all matching groups in a list of lists with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, search, dataframe

I would like to find all cases for all ids in a Pandas DataFrame.
What would be an efficient solution? I have around 10k of records and it is processed server-side. Would it be a good idea to create a new DataFrame, or is there a more efficient data structure I can use? A case is satisfied when an id contains all names in a case.

**Input (Pandas DataFrame)**

```
id | name |
-----------
1  | bla1 |
2  | bla2 |
2  | bla3 |
2  | bla4 |
3  | bla5 |
4  | bla9 |
5  | bla6 |
5  | bla7 |
6  | bla8 |
```

**Cases**

```
names [
  [bla2, bla3, bla4], #case 1
  [bla1, bla3, bla7], #case 2
  [bla3, bla1, bla6], #case 3
  [bla6, bla7] #case 4
]
```

**Needed output (unless there is a more efficient way)**

```
id | case1 | case2 | case3 | case4 |
------------------------------------
1  | 0     | 0     | 0     | 0     |
2  | 1     | 0     | 0     | 0     |
3  | 0     | 0     | 0     | 0     |
4  | 0     | 0     | 0     | 0     |
5  | 0     | 0     | 0     | 1     |
6  | 0     | 0     | 0     | 0     |
```

Comment: I think your expected output is incorrect. I'm getting something different.

Comment: id = 1 does not meet case2 and case3 because it doesn't have the bla3, bla7, bla6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
names = [
   ['bla2', 'bla3', 'bla4'], # case 1
   ['bla1', 'bla3', 'bla7'], # case 2
   ['bla3', 'bla1', 'bla6'], # case 3
   ['bla6', 'bla7']          # case 4
]

df = df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: \
                pd.Series([int(pd.Series(y).isin(x['name']).all()) for y in names]))\
       .rename(columns=lambda x: 'case{}'.format(x + 1))

df
+------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   id |   case1 |   case2 |   case3 |   case4 |
|------+---------+---------+---------+---------|
|    1 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |
|    2 |       1 |       0 |       0 |       0 |
|    3 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |
|    5 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       1 |
|    6 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |
+------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

First, `groupby` `id`, and then apply apply a check successively on each case, for each group. The objective is to check whether all items in a group will match with a given case. This is handled by the `isin` in conjunction with the list comprehension. The outer `pd.Series` will expand the result to separate columns and `df.rename` is used to rename the columns.

Comment: @COLDSPEED There is something wrong in my output. Input: https://i.imgur.com/8QkduKp.jpg Output: https://i.imgur.com/WtlFNot.jpg

Comment: @COLDSPEED Assigning the operations to a new variable instead of df helped solved it.

Comment: @COLSPEED any idea how I can get the ids of all records that have  atleast one case=1? Not sure how to access the id’s since you grouped the data on ids.

Comment: @orangetacos I think this should do: `df.loc[df.iloc[:, 1:].sum(1) > 0, 'id']`

Comment: @COLDSPEED There is no "id": https://i.imgur.com/LweDUBW.png
I think it is because you grouped it on "id", right?

Comment: @orangetacos It seems it is there in your index itself. No problem, first do `df = df.reset_index(name='id')`. And then do the step above.

Comment: @COLDSPEED Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: @orangetacos When doing the groupby in the first place, specify: `df.groupby('id', as_index=False)`. Hope that works. If not, you may need to open another Q.

Comment: @orangetacos Really vexing. Open a new Q, perhaps...?

Comment: I am wondering if there is a way to directly get the ids as a list based on the `case1 =1 or case2=1 or case3=1 or case4=1` conditions without creating extra columns.

Comment: @orangetacos maybe remove the outer pd.Series call? Idk... you're asking a lot of follow up questions here... ;-p

Comment: You are right, but it would be unnecessary to create a new question.The thing is, in this question I asked a solution for only 2 columns. In real life I have more columns that I want to keep.  This solution doesn't append the new cases to the existing dataframe.

Comment: I created a new question, in case you are interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46301211/find-all-matching-groups-in-dataframe-without-extra-columns-in-python-pandas