# How to filter out pandas DataFrame records that are are not equal to cases in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, search, dataframe, filter

I have a pandas DataFrame that consists over 10k of records. I would like to keep the rows that have all names in one of more cases in the name list. An id can be equal to multiple cases.

Id 2 is in output because `bla2`, `bla3`, `bla4` is equal to `case 1` in `name` list. Id 5 is in output because `bla6` and `bla7` is equal to `case 4` in `name` list.
Id 1 is not in output because it doesn't have `bla3` and `bla7` (`case 2`). And so on..

**Input**

```
id | name | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS] |
--------------------------------------
1  | bla1 | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS] |
2  | bla2 | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS] |
2  | bla3 | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS] |
2  | bla4 | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS] |
3  | bla5 | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS] |
4  | bla9 | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS] |
5  | bla6 | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS] |
5  | bla7 | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS] |
6  | bla8 | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS] |
```

**Needed output**

```
id | name | [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS]
--------------------------------------
2  | bla2 |
2  | bla3 |
2  | bla4 |
5  | bla6 |
5  | bla7 |
```

**Because**

```
names [
  [bla2, bla3, bla4], #case 1
  [bla1, bla3, bla7], #case 2
  [bla3, bla1, bla6], #case 3
  [bla6, bla7] #case 4
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [filtration](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration) with a bit modified [original solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46275034/2901002) with [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.any.html) for return at least one `True`:

```
def f(x):
    a = any([(x['name'].isin(y)).all() & pd.Series(y).isin(x['name']).all() for y in names])
    return (a)

df1 = (df.groupby('id').filter(f))

print (df1)
   id  name  [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS]
1   2  bla2  [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS]
2   2  bla3  [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS]
3   2  bla4  [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS]
6   5  bla6  [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS]
7   5  bla7  [A LOT OF OTHER COLUMNS]
```

Comment: There is something wrong. It still prints out the records of for example `id = 2` that have names that are not listed in `names`: https://i.imgur.com/oj05rTs.png

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I was looking for! I have been trying a lot of similar things, but never got it working. I was trying to do this in a single line, apparently this df1 solves it. Thanks you very much!

Comment: Would be nice if you could upvote my question too (only if you think my question deserves it). :)

Comment: I try upvote question where I answering, because I remember how is hard get reputation points ;) So I upvte before and now your old question too ;)

Comment: Last question: How can I combine the following condition  `.filter(lambda x: (pd.Series([(pd.Series(y).isin(x['name']).all()) for y in names])).any()))` with `OR column3 < datetime.datetime(2014-12-01)`? So basically the name list check OR date check...

Comment: Hmmm,  it seems need `a = any([(x['name'].isin(y)).all() & pd.Series(y).isin(x['name']).all() | (x['column3'] < '2014-12-01').all() for y in names])` if want all values less as date

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mask I.e

```
 acceptable = set([name1, name 2...])
 df[df[name] in acceptable]
```